# Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0.0": b'Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, docker-registry, xlib

I'm working on a gui app in docker. It works good on linux host machine but the below error is appearing.

```
import pystray
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystray/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
Icon = backend().Icon
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystray/__init__.py", line 56, in backend
return candidate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystray/__init__.py", line 36, in xorg
from . import _xorg as backend; return backend
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pystray/_xorg.py", line 36, in <m odule>
display = Xlib.display.Display()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 167, in _ _init__
raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0.0": b'Authorizat ion required, but no authorization protocol specified
```

The code I'm trying to run is

```
import Xlib.display # Create a display to verify that we have an X connection
display = Xlib.display.Display()
display.close()
del display
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have a read here... https://l10nn.medium.com/running-x11-applications-with-docker-75133178d090